# How to resolve pathspec not matching any file known to git when checking out a single, deleted file?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a branch `feature` that has come off of `develop` and is ahead of it.
A combination of `stash pop`s and `merge develop`s have resulted in a commit that includes a `rm` for particular file.

I'm trying to undo this delete by checking out the file from the commit before this delete with:

```
name@machine ~/path/inside/the/repo/to/the/parent/dir
$ git checkout megalongshaofthecommitthatdeletedthefile^ -- filename.ext
```

but get

```
error: pathspec 'filename.ext' did not match any file(s) know to git.
```

I've tried checking out files that haven't been deleted, but git is still refusing to check out the undeleted file.

How can I tell git where to get this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the pathspec issue is specifiying the parent directory, relative to the directory bash is looking at, rather than just the filename, because git is not necessarily running in the same directory that bash is "on".

Assuming git is running at `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/`

```
name@machine ~/path/inside/the/repo/to/the/parent/dir
$ git checkout megalongshaofthecommitthatdeletedthefile^ -- filename.ext
```

will look for `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/filename.ext`.

Instead, run:

```
name@machine ~/path/inside/the/repo/to/the/parent/dir
$ git checkout megalongshaofthecommitthatdeletedthefile^ -- ../dir/filename.ext
```

which will look for `C:/repodir/path/inside/the/repo/to/the/parent/dir/filename.ext`

Answer (score 3):

> How can I tell git where to get this file?

#### What can be done?

1. use `git reflog` and checkout the previous commit before the changes if you need to.

   > reflog is the full history of your repository which allow you to go back to any desired point in time
2. `git log --follow <file>` will display the commits where the file was modified (last change will be the first one)

   > This command will display all the log entries for the given file so you can grab the required commit and take the file form there using `git checkout SHA-1 file_path`
3. `git bisect`  to search in which commit the file was removed.

   > Bisect is the way to search for "bugs" and or changes made to the repository use it to track when the file was deleted. you can write script that search if the file exists and run it with the `git bisect --run...` flag
4. Once you have the desired SHA-1 use `git revert SHA-1` to "undo" the changes made in the given commit. I assume you want to do it in a new branch to be safe.
5. If you need only the file and not the rest of the changes:
   `git checkout SHA-1 -- file_path`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I've already got the commit (and its sha hash) where it was deleted. I'm trying to undo this commit using that and git can't find the file.

Comment: There are other changes in that commit that I want, I only want to revert the rm of this file for that commit.

Comment: No problem. `git checkout SHA-1 -- file_path` - it will checkout the file from the given commit

Comment: It wouldn't, that would checkout the delete, which is why I'm running `git checkout SHA-1^ -- file_path` to get the file before the delete. But at this point, git errors that it can't find the file. Which is the problem in the question.

Comment: What format should `file_path` be in? Relative to the root of the repo, relative to the directory bash is on? Fully qualified from the C:\? Something else?

Comment: The file path is the relative path starting form the git project.

Comment: If you still have problems you can checkout the branch at the given commit and grab your file from this snapshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78333/discussion-between-stuperuser-and-codewizard).